# How to vertically stack elements inside a column with Bulma?

Tags: css, bulma

This is a very simple question - but I can't figure it out from reading the Bulma docs.

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="columns is-mobile">
    <div class="column">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the `textarea` and `button` to stack vertically instead of horizontally. I know I can use the `display: block` attribute to achieve the correct behavior - but considering Bulma is based on flexbox, I would think there is a better way to vertically align elements using flexbox based attributes. I tried setting `flex-direction` to `column` in the root element, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulma takes care of that with `.textarea` class.

Solution based on **Bulma:**
Add `.textarea` class in **textarea** tag.

```
<div class="columns is-mobile">
    <div class="column">
        <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
        <button>Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative:**
Add these CSS attributes to your `textarea`:

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
```

A good practice is:
Form tags should be wrapped in a `.control` **container**.
When combining several controls in a **form**, use the `.field` class as a **container**, to keep the spacing consistent.

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="control">
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I would make this work without the `textarea` class? Because at runtime, my `textarea` will be replaced by a Code Mirror.

Comment: @Roymunson Updated my answer! :)